# Randomly sampling data by several groups with conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, sample

I have a data frame with Likert responses to 7 question types about 10 voices. Here's a sample of my data:

```
> dput(cor1)
structure(list(ID = structure(c(49L, 78L, 81L, 72L, 60L, 95L, 
35L, 16L, 44L, 89L, 96L, 24L, 48L, 91L, 94L, 36L, 57L, 75L, 17L, 
59L, 73L, 24L, 55L, 64L, 20L, 41L, 27L, 75L, 32L, 28L, 73L, 82L, 
61L, 52L, 89L, 7L, 84L, 81L, 39L, 98L, 81L, 36L, 26L, 92L, 50L, 
77L, 25L, 54L, 59L, 38L, 16L, 63L, 77L, 27L, 99L, 39L, 4L, 3L, 
86L, 40L, 52L, 13L, 1L, 12L, 96L, 3L, 76L, 31L, 100L, 35L, 18L, 
86L, 42L, 53L, 29L, 17L, 37L, 26L, 27L, 97L, 88L, 74L, 11L, 91L, 
69L, 45L, 8L, 55L, 37L, 60L, 58L, 68L, 90L, 78L, 81L, 36L, 47L, 
90L, 42L, 16L, 71L, 66L, 39L, 45L, 99L, 25L, 64L, 42L, 1L, 58L, 
50L, 82L, 44L, 78L, 25L, 98L, 13L, 58L, 69L, 96L, 44L, 83L, 46L, 
99L, 67L, 90L, 72L, 45L, 69L, 49L, 100L, 65L, 34L, 74L, 28L, 
94L, 80L, 45L, 30L, 51L, 54L, 30L, 85L, 94L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 21L, 
28L, 66L, 57L, 91L, 10L, 72L, 10L, 7L, 98L, 1L, 38L, 89L, 59L, 
72L, 65L, 61L, 86L, 19L, 9L, 76L, 50L, 53L, 19L, 43L, 46L, 74L, 
94L, 97L, 39L, 86L, 93L, 25L, 95L, 77L, 28L, 75L, 77L, 67L, 7L, 
50L, 36L, 95L, 97L, 15L, 42L, 10L, 38L, 33L, 90L, 32L, 8L, 63L, 
92L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 50L, 51L, 71L, 30L, 29L, 84L, 3L, 20L, 67L, 
89L, 65L, 3L, 14L, 59L, 36L, 47L, 80L, 61L, 90L, 19L, 87L, 38L, 
100L, 82L, 43L, 27L, 9L, 20L, 62L, 99L, 54L, 78L, 62L, 1L, 81L, 
44L, 93L, 89L, 85L, 82L, 34L, 95L, 36L, 6L, 83L, 81L, 12L, 50L, 
63L, 11L, 42L, 10L, 81L, 52L, 22L, 93L, 6L, 29L, 34L, 2L, 48L, 
2L, 10L, 16L, 36L, 48L, 9L, 80L, 29L, 90L, 99L, 22L, 61L, 61L, 
63L, 43L, 93L, 36L, 5L, 19L, 37L, 51L, 42L, 97L, 38L, 12L, 48L, 
58L, 84L, 38L, 75L, 20L, 98L, 61L, 2L, 38L, 89L, 31L, 82L, 15L, 
93L, 32L, 66L, 90L, 60L, 15L, 45L, 27L, 85L, 52L, 18L, 64L, 74L, 
30L, 49L, 3L, 48L, 6L, 51L, 9L, 7L, 80L, 2L, 80L, 92L, 48L, 11L, 
47L, 70L, 99L, 36L, 6L, 15L, 53L, 8L, 39L, 2L, 56L, 8L, 30L, 
58L, 99L, 50L, 45L, 10L, 75L, 68L, 87L, 21L, 16L, 18L, 96L, 18L, 
77L, 64L, 15L, 11L, 97L, 85L, 66L, 91L, 13L, 67L, 53L, 85L, 50L, 
6L, 89L, 35L, 32L, 65L, 38L, 16L, 61L, 88L, 35L, 20L, 99L, 87L, 
92L, 49L, 80L, 42L, 54L, 99L, 9L, 56L, 57L, 83L, 77L, 7L, 25L, 
46L, 11L, 39L, 37L, 80L, 6L, 59L, 2L, 83L, 88L, 84L, 23L, 25L, 
18L, 41L, 47L, 39L, 86L, 77L, 100L, 90L, 84L, 44L, 48L, 42L, 
84L, 92L, 31L, 20L, 96L, 46L, 36L, 41L, 82L, 24L, 98L, 63L, 96L, 
54L, 27L, 42L, 29L, 50L, 64L, 36L, 89L, 13L, 80L, 32L, 45L, 16L, 
94L, 25L, 72L, 43L, 85L, 73L, 76L, 8L, 77L, 74L, 60L, 80L, 34L, 
38L, 7L, 43L, 42L, 66L, 95L, 86L, 100L, 4L, 99L, 16L, 90L, 69L, 
6L, 56L, 17L, 33L, 46L, 73L, 6L, 39L, 98L, 50L, 4L, 63L, 98L, 
98L, 30L, 12L, 24L, 86L, 62L, 6L, 38L, 13L, 25L, 11L, 62L, 95L, 
3L, 87L, 63L, 70L, 46L, 67L, 27L, 20L, 38L, 55L, 26L, 16L, 4L, 
87L, 23L, 17L, 8L, 21L, 34L, 98L, 56L, 21L, 33L, 82L, 32L, 40L, 
18L, 56L, 16L, 98L, 9L, 55L, 25L, 99L, 14L, 99L, 15L, 58L, 18L, 
52L, 30L, 21L, 37L, 49L, 52L, 18L, 83L, 91L, 12L, 89L, 13L, 63L, 
15L, 62L, 54L, 45L, 56L, 93L, 65L, 15L, 94L, 56L, 42L, 44L, 55L, 
100L, 7L, 42L, 17L, 3L, 34L, 16L, 29L, 69L, 88L, 31L, 64L, 55L, 
96L, 27L, 51L, 70L, 47L, 83L, 50L, 87L, 86L, 39L, 46L, 44L, 47L, 
52L, 78L, 26L, 53L, 24L, 43L, 24L, 38L, 94L, 96L, 55L, 54L, 91L, 
6L, 16L, 44L, 48L, 80L, 27L, 33L, 25L, 66L, 45L, 99L, 53L, 12L, 
49L, 46L, 33L, 56L, 88L, 29L, 24L, 88L, 62L, 82L, 61L, 100L, 
77L, 89L, 65L, 18L, 24L, 96L, 41L, 70L, 20L, 75L, 81L, 50L, 47L, 
93L, 39L, 16L, 4L, 65L, 32L, 57L, 10L, 12L, 69L, 43L, 81L, 97L, 
74L, 9L, 87L, 33L, 60L, 73L, 14L, 17L, 56L, 27L, 41L, 35L, 64L, 
19L, 92L, 42L, 5L, 58L, 19L, 17L, 31L, 50L, 78L, 10L, 62L, 56L, 
62L, 54L, 15L, 25L, 66L, 4L, 98L, 89L, 26L, 79L, 96L, 9L, 60L, 
11L, 71L, 8L, 79L, 39L, 94L, 6L, 13L, 90L, 38L, 38L, 54L, 84L, 
54L, 92L, 68L, 41L, 7L, 61L, 71L, 98L, 22L, 47L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 
69L, 19L, 99L, 24L, 19L, 51L, 91L, 56L, 82L, 35L, 93L, 15L, 55L, 
87L, 19L, 84L, 22L, 100L, 45L, 43L, 90L, 40L, 64L, 35L, 34L, 
85L, 97L, 21L, 16L, 7L, 49L, 55L, 26L, 62L, 80L, 69L, 52L, 74L, 
8L, 52L, 12L, 18L, 80L, 63L, 79L, 89L, 35L, 9L, 22L, 61L, 37L, 
73L, 91L, 68L, 68L, 80L, 20L, 70L, 27L, 76L, 13L, 5L, 74L, 69L, 
29L, 68L, 91L, 16L, 3L, 19L, 20L, 31L, 60L, 77L, 53L, 48L, 5L, 
15L, 47L, 58L, 2L, 51L, 27L, 23L, 50L, 97L, 42L, 53L, 47L, 13L, 
100L, 12L, 11L, 2L, 86L, 58L, 9L, 23L, 28L, 65L, 77L, 8L, 45L, 
38L, 6L, 64L, 89L, 78L, 18L, 88L, 73L, 1L, 94L, 27L, 97L, 33L, 
75L, 5L, 56L, 48L, 61L, 39L, 76L, 100L, 45L, 87L, 54L, 76L, 8L, 
59L, 64L, 96L, 45L, 74L, 39L, 33L, 33L, 17L, 28L, 57L, 24L, 75L, 
38L, 80L, 94L, 3L, 34L, 7L, 90L, 67L, 45L, 97L, 30L, 55L, 88L, 
15L, 2L, 32L, 86L, 62L, 76L, 24L, 68L, 37L, 3L, 37L, 92L, 12L, 
75L, 10L, 73L, 44L, 32L, 56L, 99L, 21L, 6L, 76L, 42L, 81L, 40L, 
35L, 11L, 11L, 76L, 34L, 38L, 96L, 66L, 74L, 19L, 79L, 28L, 13L, 
73L, 15L, 48L, 64L, 58L, 90L, 32L, 24L, 95L, 15L, 90L, 35L, 100L, 
61L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 91L, 45L, 78L, 84L, 1L, 54L, 93L, 76L, 20L, 
11L, 74L, 81L, 27L, 49L, 48L, 18L, 21L, 48L, 51L, 31L, 65L, 18L, 
84L, 99L, 76L, 79L, 1L, 71L, 37L, 99L, 23L, 35L, 3L, 41L, 83L, 
89L, 4L, 51L, 88L, 85L, 63L, 59L, 8L, 50L, 2L, 69L, 3L, 64L, 
24L, 68L, 93L, 83L, 22L, 82L, 39L, 98L, 12L, 93L, 30L, 59L, 17L, 
88L, 41L, 28L, 55L, 39L, 54L, 5L, 71L, 24L), levels = c("3076960", 
"3077063", "3077134", "3077775", "3079376", "3117052", "3117053", 
"3117055", "3117058", "3117071", "3117072", "3117084", "3117092", 
"3117115", "3117158", "3117196", "3117249", "3118375", "3123348", 
"3123358", "3123364", "3123379", "3123387", "3123396", "3123397", 
"3123402", "3123403", "3123423", "3123433", "3123444", "3123499", 
"3123543", "3123713", "3123837", "3187747", "3187753", "3187986", 
"3206823", "3206826", "3206827", "3206828", "3206829", "3206830", 
"3206838", "3206844", "3207921", "3218018", "3218393", "3076980", 
"3077130", "3077181", "3077221", "3080756", "3117057", "3117059", 
"3117061", "3117065", "3117068", "3117073", "3117078", "3117088", 
"3117090", "3117162", "3117170", "3117175", "3117327", "3117922", 
"3123344", "3123345", "3123346", "3123354", "3123361", "3123367", 
"3123381", "3123388", "3123392", "3123404", "3123406", "3123411", 
"3123418", "3123427", "3123446", "3123474", "3123666", "3123757", 
"3187745", "3187918", "3189130", "3206813", "3206831", "3206833", 
"3206834", "3206837", "3206839", "3206848", "3218015", "3218023", 
"3218024", "3249231", "3250005"), class = "factor"), stimulus.accent = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), levels = c("SSBE", 
"Belfast", "Birmingham", "Bradford", "Bristol", "Cardiff", "Glasgow", 
"Liverpool", "London", "Newcastle"), class = "factor"), question.type = structure(c(5L, 
6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
6L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 
2L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
6L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
7L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
7L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 
1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
7L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 
2L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
7L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 
5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
7L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
7L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 2L), levels = c("status", "solidarity", 
"dynamism", "crime", "morally bad", "morally ambiguous", "morally good"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), response = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 
4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 
4L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
2L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
4L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1000L), groups = structure(list(
    stimulus.accent = structure(1:10, levels = c("SSBE", "Belfast", 
    "Birmingham", "Bradford", "Bristol", "Cardiff", "Glasgow", 
    "Liverpool", "London", "Newcastle"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:100, 101:200, 201:300, 301:400, 401:500, 501:600, 601:700, 
        701:800, 801:900, 901:1000), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

There are 100 participants, 10 voices, 7 question types. Each participant heard every voice, but did not answer every question type. Additionally there are an unequal number of responses for each participant for each question type, so there are an unequal number of responses for each question type for each voice.

I want to randomly sample the data so that there are an equal number of responses per question type for each voice. Currently the minimum number of responses per voice & per question type is 50, so that's the number I'd like for each question type for each voice. This would mean instead of a 10,000 rows I would have 3500. But crucially I want to be sure that each participant (ID) is only sampled once for each question type (question.type) for each voice (stimulus.accent).

I've tried using `group_by()` and `sample_n()` from `dplyr`, but can't work out how to set different target sampling for different groupings.

LMK if I've done any of this wrong, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Currently the minimum number of responses per voice & per question type is 50

It looks to me like this isn't the case, unless I've misunderstood what you've put, e.g.:

```
count(cor1, stimulus.accent, question.type)
```

shows there is at least one group of accent/question type with only 1 row.

That aside, it looks like this can be solved with `slice_sample` (which has superseded `sample_n`). If you want to ensure there is only one row per ID, you can simply sample a single row for each ID, accent and question type first.

```
# 50 random rows per accent and question type
cor1 %>%
  group_by(stimulus.accent, question.type) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 50)

# Or, first ensure maximum of one row per ID, per accent and question type
cor1 %>%
  group_by(ID, stimulus.accent, question.type) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 1) %>%
  group_by(stimulus.accent, question.type) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 50)
```

Comment: Sorry, it's cos I couldn't post my whole data set here as it's too large, but I know it's helpful to include some kind of sense of what your data looks like on here!
I was referring to the minimum number of responses *in total* rather than *per participant*. e.g. for question.type MA, for each voice, there are minimum 50 responses (50 listeners answered this question type, all heard all voices)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response - I ran the second code (similar to what I tried with sample_n actually!) and it threw up this error:

Error in `slice_sample()`:
! Problem while computing indices.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: stimulus.accent = SSBE, question.type = status.
Caused by error in `sample.int()`:
! cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Comment: That indicates that the minimum number of responses per stimulus.accent and question.type is less than 50. If you are using that code on your full dataset then it might be because after you take only one row per ID per group, the minimum is less than 50. Using `slice_sample(n = min(count(., stimulus.accent, question.type)$n))` at the end should avoid the error

Comment: I think this is slicing in the wrong order, because yes in the original data: > table(cor$question.type)

           status        solidarity          dynamism             crime       morally bad morally ambiguous      morally good 
             1920              1920               960              2600              1040               520              1040

i.e. minimum response number for a question group is 520 = 52 for each voice, so not lower than 50...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with package [`sampling`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=sampling).
The main function is `strata`, that stratifies the sampling by variables passed in `strataname`. I define the strata samples sizes to be equal to 1 only because stratum 69 only has 1 element.

```r
library(sampling)

tbl <- table(cor1[2:3])
size <- rep(1, length(tbl[tbl != 0]))

s <- strata(cor1, stratanames = c("stimulus.accent", "question.type"),
            size = size, method = "srswor")
cor1_sample <- getdata(cor1, s)

str(cor1_sample)
#> 'data.frame':    69 obs. of  7 variables:
#>  $ ID             : Factor w/ 100 levels "3076960","3077063",..: 57 60 61 72 41 25 44 65 95 43 ...
#>  $ response       : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4"<..: 5 4 1 3 5 3 5 3 7 6 ...
#>  $ stimulus.accent: Factor w/ 10 levels "SSBE","Belfast",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
#>  $ question.type  : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "status"<"solidarity"<..: 5 6 4 7 2 3 1 4 7 2 ...
#>  $ ID_unit        : int  17 5 33 4 26 47 9 132 181 172 ...
#>  $ Prob           : num  0.1 0.1 0.0417 0.1 0.05 ...
#>  $ Stratum        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>